# Rails 4: ActiveAdmin/Devise -- filling in `reset_password_token` field when editing user in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

So I have Devise on the backend running authorization for a `User` model. I also have ActiveAdmin running in conjunction with this.

Here's app/admin/user.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  # Specify which columns we want to appear in our ActiveAdmin index page
  index do
    column :name
    column :email
    column :class
    column :major
    column :biography

    # Adds view/edit/delete actions
    default_actions
  end

  controller do
    def permitted_params
      params.permit!
    end
  end
end
```

**Here's the problem:**  When Users sign up, their `reset_password_token` attributes are empty. So say 5 users sign up. I then go into the ActiveAdmin portal, and try to edit the users' information. Okay fine, so I edit the name of the first user; the edit page looks like this:

[image]

I *only* fill in the `major` attribute, for instance, as that's all I want to update. The user saves successfully.

Then, while still in the ActiveAdmin portal, I go to edit my second user, and edit his `major` attribute as well. However, when I hit `Update User`, I get an error, saying:

`QLite3::ConstraintException: column reset_password_token is not unique: UPDATE "actives" SET "encrypted_password" = ?, "reset_password_token" = ?, "major" = ?, "pledge_class" = ?, "biography" = ?, "current_sign_in_at" = ?, "last_sign_in_at" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "actives"."id" = 49`

I'm assuming this error occurs simply because there is already a user with blank `reset_password_token.` (If I enter something random into the `reset_password_token` field, the update goes through successfully).

What is the normal solution to this? Do I initialize the reset_password_token somehow? Or do I just have to enter something random each time I update a User... (doesn't seem very efficient or logical).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `reset_password_token` shouldn't be part of the form. It is an internal field used by Devise when a password reset is requested by a user. Hiding most of the Devise internal fields would best:

- reset_password_token
- password reset sent at
- remember created at
- current sign-in at
- last sign-in at
- etc...